# How do I make a http request from an asp.net middleware?

Tags: asp.net, http

I have a middleware which needs to call off to an external service to check for some state and then act on it.  I'm wondering how I go about making a request from middleware?

I've seen some docs about having a HttpClientFactory service, but I'm not really sure how I make that available to my middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

This allows you to create a client in your middleware and send any request you need.

Example:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient()){
  try   
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
     // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }  
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");  
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
}
```